# Potential pitfalls in node/express to have callbacks complete AFTER a response is returned to the client?

Tags: node.js

I want to write a callback that takes a bit of time to complete an external IO operation, but I do not want it to interfere when sending data back to the client.  I don't care about waiting for callback completion for purposes of the reply back to the client, but if the callback results in an error, I would like to log it.  About 80% of executions will result in this callback executing after the response is sent back to the client and the connection is closed.

My approach works well and I have not seen any problems, but I would like to know whether there are any pitfalls in this approach that I may be unaware of.  I would think that node's evented IO would handle this without issue, but I want to make sure before I commit this architecture to production.  Any issues that should make me reconsider this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're not trying to reference that response object after the response is sent, this will not cause any problems.  There's nothing special about a request handler that cares one bit about callbacks in its code being invoked after the response is generated.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured.  Just looking for confirmation.